# A new property value stored thru a setter takes affect before execution

Tags: javascript, class, setter

I'm creating 4 instances of the class Coordinates. Next I'm changing one of the values thru the setter.

```
class Coordinates {
    constructor(lat, lng) {
        this._lat = lat;
        this._lng = lng;
    }
    get lat() { return this._lat; }
    get lng() { return this._lng; }
    set lat(newLat) { this._lat = newLat; }
    set lng(newLng) { this._lng = newLng; }
}

let points = [];
for (let p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
    const point = new Coordinates(p, p);
    points.push(point);
}
console.log(points);  // Shows the 55, although the setter wasn't executed
points[1].lat = 55;
console.log(points); // Shows the 55 (as expected)
```

The first console.log shows 0/0, 55/1, 2/2, 3/3. I actually expected 0/0, 1/1, 2/2, 3/3, because I didn't executed the setter. The 2nd log shows 0/0, 55/1, 2/2, 3/3, as expected.
Can somebody help me to understand, pls?

Comment: Are u sure ? I ran it on Nodejs and first console.log() prints as expected.

Comment: I ran it with Firefox or Chrome. Both show 55 in the first sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot reproduce this in Node.js, but can reproduce in Chrome console, I suppose this is because the `points` variable is displayed in the console lazily, i.e. it has a live reevaluation when you click on it to see the elements in details. If you try this, you can see the issue is gone as now you have string primitives instead of live objects.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(points));
points[1].lat = 55;
console.log(JSON.stringify(points));
```